# Json to pandas dataframde

Tags: json, pandas, request

I would like to get the list of messages from this page https://stocktwits.com/symbol/SPY they provide a free api where I can get json file https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/SPY.json.

```
import requests
import json

request=requests.get('https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/SPY.json')
json_data=request.json()
```

I used the code above, but I keep getting error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` I would greatly appriceate it if someone could help me get the list of messages in pandas dataframe form

Comment: What do you get when your print  `request`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM <Response [403]>

Comment: As you can see it's returning 403 status code which means that you have insufficient rights to access this API

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I can open the link with my browser and I get the json file

Comment: Interesting, Try passing a custom user-agent in the header and see if it's working. Like `requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})`

Comment: Okay, great, thank you, now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to pass the `User-Agent` header to get the expected response.

```
>>> import requests
>>> request = requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})
```

Once the request is successful you can use  `pandas.read_json` API to construct the dataframe from JSON returned from the server.